# Is it fine to restore a reserved field in a proto definition?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

Say I commented out a field in a proto definition and set the number in the `reserved` fields, but now I want to restore it. Can I take it out of `reserved` and assign the number back? Or should I use a new number. Are there any implications on the former?

e.g. If I want to use manufacturer again

```
message ProductDetail {
    reserved 2;
    string name = 1;   
    // string manufacturer = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fine, as long as the meaning hasn't changed.